# Why can't i get xml back - jquery, sharepoint, webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am sending a jquery/ajax post request to a sharepoint service and want to get xml back so I can use it to create a survey. This is my first time using jQuery so I am pretty new to it. Any help is appreciated. 
Btw I am getting a "loaded" alert so I knwo the jquery is loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('loaded'); 
        var xmlData = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>Shared Documents</listName><query><Query   xmlns=''><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query></query><viewFields><ViewFields xmlns=''  /></viewFields><queryOptions><QueryOptions xmlns='' /></queryOptions></GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://mkspintrat01/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: xmlData,
            complete: SuccessFunc,
            error: ErrorFunc,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

 function SuccessFunc(result) { 
     // xml node with namespace need to be handled differently for jQuery
     $(result.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
     });

} function ErrorFunc(result) {
    alert("failed");
        //alert(result.responseText);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you send the request? Does the `SuccessFunc` or `ErrorFunc` get called? Have you checked the console for errors? What is the format of the response? Assuming it's XML as you've set then there will be no `responseXML` property - `result` will hold the XML itself.

Comment: This is what I am getting     SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.   The format is supposed to be XML and I dont understand what you mean in the last part

Comment: Ok you can ignore the last part of my first comment. The problem is the request is not being served as access to the file is denied. You need to determine why that is. Does your site use authorization headers?